# No AVD/SDK manager in Intellij?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, sdk

Recently I had some issues with Eclipse, so I decided to use an another IDE for Android Development and I recieved some recommendations that I should use Intellij.

Now my problem is that I have set up the path to the SDK and JDK. However, I cannot see "Android" section under tools. I can use my Android SDKs when I try to make a project, but I cannot open managers.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This feature is available since 2017.2 version. Currently in the [Preview state](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/).